# java (beginner) converting scientific notation to decimal

Tags: java, decimal, scientific-notation

if

```
double d =  1.999e-4
```

I want my output to be 0.0001999.

How can I do it?

Comment: You should select an answer and/or upvote answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.#####");  

String f = formatter.format(d);
```

You can explore the sub classes of `NumberFormat` class to know more details.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose there is a method in BigDecimal Class called `toPlainString()`.
e.g. if the the BigDecimal is 1.23e-8 then the method returns 0.0000000124.

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("1.23E-8");

System.out.println(d.toPlainString());
```

Above code prints 0.0000000123, then you can process the string as per your requirement.

Comment: my excelsheet number is 42.063706, but returns 42.06370600000000337104211212135851383209228515625

Comment: @AbdullahNurum what method are you using to read in the excel sheet and construct the BigDecimal object? When I construct it with the string literal "42.063706" it outputs the correct thing (same as input). Make sure you aren't storing it in a floating point value in between reading and making the BigDecimal object. You should keep it as a string during that time, in order to not lose precision.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
    double d = 1.999e-4;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(7);
    System.out.println(nf.format(d));
```

Check out the documentation of `NumberFormat`'s methods to format your `double` as you see fit.

`DecimalFormat` is a special case of `NumberFormat` as its constructor states, I don't think that you need its functionality for your case. Check out their documentation if you are confused. Use the factory method `getInstance()` of `NumberFormat` for your convenience.

Comment: Thank you very much! (BTW  NumberFormat and DecimalFormat which one should I use??)

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to print like that.

```
System.out.printf("%1$.10f", d);
```

you can change 10f, 10=number of decimal places you want.

Comment: Thank you very much!  what does 1$  = ??

Comment: 1$=argument index, if you had System.out.printf("%3$.10f", e,f,d);
you would use 3$ as your target is d. Details here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over

```
java.text.DecimalFormat
```

and

```
java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
```